# Oracle BI Publisher - appropriate or not?

Tags: discussion

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/bi-publisher/index.html

In my previous company we (DBA+Dev team) got involved with this product. I think it's more likely to end up in SO, but believe it might be useful to many other DBAs.

Comment: Yes, I think it's appropriate.

Comment: So I think it's appropriate, as long as this doesn't involve doing work with the APIs (i.e. JAVA etc.). Pls. comment if u can.

Comment: Dunno what this product is, but [BI is now officially in scope](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/q/503/2660) here on DBA.SE.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think SO is predestined? SF and SU are possible candidates too. So why not keep it here.

I don't think it is off topic.
I don't think it should be migrated to another site.

Comment: I thought SO because of the programming & non-admin tasks involved around it. On the other side it's quite tough to install (at least before it was). Also, I would like to discuss it's Java-API, so where should that go?

Answer (score 2):

**It depends**.  The product isn't a database even though it is made by Oracle.  It does use an Oracle database and can use XML generated by any database, so it would depend on the specific question.

Example Questions:

> When installing Oracle BI Publisher I get an installer error of...

Probably **off topic** because it deals with installing an application.

> When installing Oracle BI Publisher I get an Oracle Error of...

Probably **on topic** because it deals with a database error.

> I am having trouble scheduling an agent in Oracle BI Publisher...
>
> Oracle BI Publisher is complaining about XML produced by my database.  The XML looks like...

Probably **off topic** because it deals with using an application.

> Oracle BI Publisher has a problem with XML produced by the following PL/SQL...

Probably **on topic** because the question is more about PL/SQL in an Oracle database than Oracle BI Publisher.

*Note: I have never used the product, so my examples may be way off.*